# How to upload file in html?

Tags: html

How to upload a file in simple html? What all tags must be used?

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you can't, HTML is a markup language which has no interaction with the server. I see you have a .php action - research `$_FILES `

Comment: you need a a code to handle the file on the server (PHP for example). a file input will allow you to select a file but will not save it on the server

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="pic" id="image">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

1. you need a form with method POST & enctype multipart/form-data
2. you need a input type file to add your file
3. you need a button to submit. (you can submit without it too... using jQuery)

Answer (score -1):

You need to do 2 changes.

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Secondly, the field tag

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```